# Creating Tiny Splinters In Plastic Using Shaders or Geometry Nodes

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, 3d-printing

I'm trying a 3D printed look. I have the layer lines down so far, but how can I generate these tiny Splinters?

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you used Geometry nodes for this?

Comment: @Crantisz The screenshot above is from a plugin that I didn't create. So far I have written a script that imports a GCode file (that's a file that a 3d printer uses to 3d print the object) and creates an object but it looks too perfect. Here's a sample of what my import looks like: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3e01.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Bump and material settings

Gunt.r answer is good, but instead of constant interpolation I would set a Linear or Beizer, this should look more realistic:

[image]

Also, you can get the required amount of bumps just by sliding colorramp's stops at the right.

### Using geometry nodes

If you want to make them "real" You can distribute some simple objects like this:

[image]

SSS should wash out edges.

Comment: I think changing the interpolation just that little bit does the job for me. Geometry nodes might add too much render time. The shader solutions seems perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A basic noise texture will get you pretty close

[image]

However, you're looking for a much lower density of detail - SO what you can do is:

Add another noise texture with a LOWER scale to mask over the top of the smaller one

[image]

I encourage you to play with the scale and the color that the color ramp outputs to understand this node setup further. Also ensure that the color ramps are set to *constant* and the `math` node is set to *divide*

Now what we need to do to actually get the dots to pop out is apply a bump map like this:

[image]

Comment: I was answering the question too quickly and forgot to mention how to add height/normals. Will update it soon

Comment: Thanks, I still got a bit of an idea. I can probably play around and get something done I suppose. I'd keep at it

Comment: how to get the stuff to pop out had been added to the answer